# How can prepareForReuse() be implemented to prevent a faded cell from acting weird?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I use self.like.alpha = 0.5 to highlight the . like button next to the user who was liked. Scrolling causes the highlight to sometimes disappear and appear next to other users.

I have figured out that I can either use A) prepareForReuse or B) do something like this pseudocode (although IsLiked would have to be confined to that session somehow) :

```
cell.like.alpha = item.isLiked ? 0.5 : 1
```

Here is my code:

In View ControllerTableViewCell.swift:

```
 @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {

 self.like.alpha = 0.5
   let ref = Database.database().reference()
let keyToPost = ref.child("likes").childByAutoId().key

ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  {(snapshot) in

    if let humans = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["humansWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]

        ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in

            if error == nil {
                ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                    if let properties = snap.value as?[String: AnyObject]{
                        if let likes = properties["humansWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                            let count = likes.count
                        let update = ["likes" : count]
                            ref.child("humans").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)

                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
ref.removeAllObservers()
 }
```

In homepage.swift(where like button is used):

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton


let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

let person: Userx = humans[indexPath.row]

cell.lblName.text = person.Education

cell.postID = self.humans[indexPath.row].postID

if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
    let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
    immy.sd_setImage(with: url)
}
return cell
}
```

I need the like fade to not go away and not go to other users when cells get reused after scrolling.

Database Structure:

```
 "humans" : {
"5VbL3Adj7teM2KNJkF4GIexBJhE2" : {
  "Coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : 42.8864,
    "longitude" : 78.8784
  },
  "Education" : "Yale Accounting",
  "PhotoPosts" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/daylike-2f938.appspot.com/o/images%2FPhotoPosts?alt=media&token=42d76567-ac42-4728-9914-1d7c2fa4d5e6",
  "WhatIamConsideringBuying" : "Twitter: Carla9",
  "caption" : 1565896677651,
  "caption1" : {
    "caption1" : 1566734644170,
    "keyToPost" : "-Ln7eM9S_pSQ_aqRPz0k"
  },
  "likes" : 82,
  "peopleWhoLike" : {
    "-LmLjHwwGj1kt5qLM20X" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LmLtlp5Sm900SV8xP4i" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LmLuOzQ0TZ9uJ_uNkkg" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LmLultcrrsG2NjEYoTe" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LmLvMseSmFhnxEGGctU" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LmLvVQokDCZLFrnhaLu" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",

  },
  "postID" : "5VbL3Adj7teM2KNJkF4GIexBJhE2",
  "users" : "carla19martin@me.com"
},
"9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2" : {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the alpha for each cell in `cellForRow` method. You should not change it based on the cell itself sending an action to your `likePressed()` method. Instead, it should reflect your underlying data model, which I assume you have cached locally.

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton
    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let person: Userx = humans[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblName.text = person.Education
    cell.postID = self.humans[indexPath.row].postID

    if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
        let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
        immy.sd_setImage(with: url)
    }

    // You need to set the alpha here in cellForRow method
    // Your idea using nil coalescing is good, as it must always be set afresh for the relevant cell (so it is correct when reused)
    // Get value of isLiked - this depends on your database and local cache
    // This is an example - accessing the isLiked property may be different depending on your data model

    cell.like.alpha = posts[indexPath.row].isLiked ? 0.5 : 1

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Is there no other way to do this, because the isLiked part may be tricky looking at the database vs acting when like is pressed? User A might have liked User B five days ago, but then the like Button shouldn't be still greyed out.

Comment: Just want to check your data structure. Is this a list where users can like other users? You’re right that a database call would slow it up, but if you have all the users in a local array, you could have an `isLiked` property for each which is quick to read and could be changed immediately in this way. You might need to call `tableView.reloadData()` though. You can then update the database model asynchronously as usual. There probably are other ways - I’m not a pro! 

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help. Yeah, there is a list where users like other users. I have now added the database in the question. How do you update the database model asynchronously? Never mind a pro, I am very new to Swift. :)

Comment: I have never used Firebase or Firestore. I see they store data as JSON, like what you have shown. A good practice is for your user interface to use a local store of data, so it responds quickly, and do updating of Firebase separately behind the scenes using background threads (see Grand Central Dispatch). Your local data would be an array of people objects - you should write a custom class for this that corresponds to the structure of the JSON objects. You can then save/load to Firebase using JSON encoding/decoding. This way, the tableview cells will quickly get their data from local array.